# How to cut image in irregular parts using pattern of vector graphic - preferabely in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to ask for your advices. I would need to cut large size TIFF file into multiple irregular parts using pattern of specially designed net formula (image attached):

[image]

[image]

The output should be multiple png files: each consist one element cutted and of the total size same as original image.

Do you have any idea how i can automate the process of cuting the file?

Comment: A voronoi pattern? Use imagemagick or any other scriptable /programmable image manipulation tool.

Comment: You'd likely need some kind of script to do this in Photoshop. There's nothing that can do this using the available tools, at least not automatically.